# ReStructuring TFS Branches

Tags: version-control, branching-and-merging

We setup our branching poorly and now we want to fix it.  We have projects where there are two or more branches that should be one branch (as in we always merge/branch all of them at the same time).  How do we change the branching so that we have one branch where before we had two or more?  How do we access the history after changing the branches?  What if the branches are in different locations (ie how do we move them)?  Will the history still work after that?

Edit:

Example 1:

Current Structure:

```
Folder1  
|--Branch1  
|  |--Project1  
|--Branch2  
|  |--Project2
```

Desired Structure:

```
Folder1  
|--Branch1  
|  |--Project1  
|  |--Project2
```

Example 2:

Current Structure:

```
Folder1  
|--Branch1  
|  |--Project1
Folder2
|--Branch2  
|  |--Project2
```

Desired Structure:

```
Folder1  
|--Branch1  
|  |--Project1  
|  |--Project2
```

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand completely what your branches look like now, and what you want them to become. Try to give more information on your structures if you can.

If you haven't read it yet, I suggest you take a look at the [TFS Branching Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) to determine the best branching methodology that will work for you.

Also, if you move any files, you will lose your history for them. This is because the move is actually a delete and recreate. The work around for this is to temporarily go to Tools->Options->Source Control->Visual Studio Team Foundation Server -> check Show Deleted items on Source Control Explorer. This will let you see the history of all the files you moved.

Comment: I am aware of the branching guide and how it Should be setup.  The problem is that it is currently setup wrong.

Comment: I think your best bet is to just get latest version of all your source code, and then move things around until you get your desired structure. Completely delete the existing structure in TFS, and then check-in this new structure. You will be able to get the history of the old structure using the method I mentioned above, but you're going to lose most of your history no matter what you end up doing anyway.